# Почему когда удаляю уникальное ограничение, то оно продолжает работать?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, constraints

```
USERDB> ALTER TABLE mw_thirdparty_service DROP CONSTRAINT mt_service_external_unq
[2021-07-05 11:34:33] completed in 112 ms
USERDB> INSERT INTO mw_thirdparty_service(
                     mw_thirdparty_service_id,
                     external_id,
                     gos_no,
                     service_name,
                     supplier_id,
                     mt_ch_limit,
                     accuracy_class,
                     wo_category_id)
                 VALUES(
                     mw_thirdparty_service_seq.nextval,
                     '44008042008733',
                     null,
                     '44008042008733',
                     669,
                     null,
                     null,
                     2)
[2021-07-05 11:34:42] [23000][1] ORA-00001: unique constraint (USERDB.MT_SERVICE_EXTERNAL_UNQ) violated
[2021-07-05 11:34:42] Position: 0
USERDB> select * from ALL_CONSTRAINTS where CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'MT_SERVICE_EXTERNAL_UNQ'
[2021-07-05 11:34:48] 0 rows retrieved in 202 ms (execution: 168 ms, fetching: 34 ms)
```

Пробовал явно указывать пользователя/cхему при указании таблицы, пробовал отключать ограничение, отключать и удалять, но оно всё ещё работает.

Поиск ограничений по этой таблице через - `all_constraints where table_name` выдаёт все ограничения, кроме нужного.
Перезагрузка БД тоже не помогла

Comment: Для воспроизведения проблемы - выложите CREATE TABLE обеих таблиц, INSERT INTO с добавлением в каждую по 1 записи, и укажите точную версию OracleDB.

Comment: Завёл пользователя, сделал нужные таблицы, чтобы воспроизвести, всё ок, constraint удаляется по нормальному. Проблема почему то только на моей бд(пользователе/схеме)

Comment: Значит, где-то что-то с пермиссиями. Попробуй сравнить права пользователя, у которого всё выполняется и у которого не очень...

Comment: пермиссии это гранты?

Comment: Угу. Права, разрешения... в документации OracleDB используется термин "privileges" (привилегии). PS. Если строго, то GRANT - это тип запроса, добавляющий привилегии.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Oracle сделал unique index с тем же названием что и constraint, который тоже надо было удалить

Не совсем так, не Oracle каким-то образом создал уникальный индекс, этот индекс уже существовал до создания ограничения, т.е. был создан явно.

При создании уникального ограничения, всегда неявно создаётся уникальный индекс с тем же именем. Этот индекс будет неявно удалён, если удалить ограничение.

Воспроизводимый пример ([fiddle 1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=677b88c2e8601cbe1d93766d5d4b9ac0)):

```
create table T (id int)
/
insert into t values (1)
/
1 row inserted.

alter table t add constraint uqt unique (id)
/
insert into t values (1)
/
ORA-00001: unique constraint (DB.UQT) violated

alter table t drop constraint uqt
/
insert into t values (1)
/
1 row inserted.
```

Если же индекс был создан явно, то при создании ограничения с тем же именем, новый индекс создан не будет, но и удалён этот индекс при удалении ограничения не будет.

Воспроизводимый пример ([fiddle 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8470f486e98dd61b086a90b873be9543)):

```
create table T (id int)
/
insert into t values (1)
/
1 row inserted.

create unique index uqt on t (id)
/
alter table t add constraint uqt unique (id)
/
insert into t values (1)
/
ORA-00001: unique constraint (DB.UQT) violated

alter table t drop constraint uqt
/
insert into t values (1)
/
ORA-00001: unique constraint (DB.UQT) violated
```

В последнем случае, можно удалить индекс одним запросом вместе с ограничением с опцией `drop index` ([fiddle 3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9afbcfa4e978e9c9cada835c5e8e1af4)):

```
alter table t drop constraint uqt drop index
/
insert into t values (1)
/
1 row inserted.
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle сделал unique index с тем же названием что и constraint, который тоже надо было удалить